# Advanced I/O redirection in a C program.(Simple Shell)

Tags: c, string, shell, unix, redirect

I'm designing a simple shell but I have a problem with advanced redirection.

I am able to do this : ls -al > a.txt

But i couldn't do this : wc < a.txt > b.txt

How can i do that?

Here is where i perform my i/o redirection :

```
char *inpu=NULL; //Inpu is a global variable.
#define CREATE_FLAGS (O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC)
#define CREATE_FLAGS1 (O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_APPEND)
#define CREATE_FLAGS2 (O_RDONLY | O_CREAT | O_APPEND)
#define CREATE_MODE (S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH)
#define MAXCHARNUM 128 
#define MAXARGNUM 32 


char *argsexec[MAXARGNUM]; /*This stores my executable arguments like cd ls.*/

void ioredirection(int f){
   int k,i,m;
   int input=-1;
   int output=-1;
   int append=-1;   
   int fdin,fdout;    

        for(k=0; k<f; k++){
            if(strcmp(argsexec[k],"<")==0){
                input=k;  // argument place of "<"
                m=1;   
        argsexec[k]=NULL;              
           }
            else if(strcmp(argsexec[k],">")==0){
                output=k; // argument place of ">"
                m=2; 
        argsexec[k]=NULL;                   
           }
            else if(strcmp(argsexec[k],">>")==0){
                append=k; // argument place of ">>"
                m=3;
        argsexec[k]=NULL;
           }
        }

           if(m==1){
            int inp1;
    fdin=open(argsexec[input+1],O_RDONLY,CREATE_MODE);
    dup2(fdin,STDIN_FILENO);
    close(fdin);
    inp1=execlp(argsexec[0],argsexec[0],NULL);
           }    

           if(m==2){          
            fdout = open(argsexec[output+1], CREATE_FLAGS, CREATE_MODE);
            dup2 (fdout, STDOUT_FILENO);
            close(fdout);
            execvp(argsexec[0],argsexec);   
           }

           if(m==3){
        fdout = open(argsexec[append+1], CREATE_FLAGS1, CREATE_MODE) ;
            dup2 (fdout, STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(fdout);
        execvp(argsexec[0],argsexec);
           }        
}
```

b is changing like this :

```
inpu=strtok(str," ");
while(inpu!=NULL){
  argsexec[b]=inpu;
  b++;
  inpu = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
```

And i'm calling it with child process.

```
if (pid==0){  
   ioredirection(b);
```

I hope it is clear to understand, my full is code really long i tried to cut it like this. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you use both tabs or spaces? Code formatting is really inconsistent and code is very hard to read.

Comment: Actually tonight i have a deadline for this school project.That's why i couldn't format it properly sorry for that.

Comment: JFYI good formatted and well-structured code is usually much easier to support and debug even when the deadline is close.

Comment: This doesn't help with your current question, but pretty much every major IDE I've used has some sort of auto-formatter. When your project is done, look up "Beautify" or "Pretty Print" or "Format Code" for your particular development environment. Then, you don't really have to worry about it. Just run the tool and it will be consistent. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran your code through a formatter and got (greatly simplified):

```
void ioredirection(int f) {
    for (k over all arguments) {
        set m based on argsexec[k]
    }
    test m against 1, 2, and 3
}
```

Thus, if there are two (or more) "re-direction" operations, the loop (`for k`) will set `m` two (or more) times.  Then, the loop having terminated, you (finally) test `m` once against each of three possible values.

The first problem should now be clear (but since this is a school project I'm not going to solve it for you :-) ).

The second problem is clear only in looking at the three tests performed on `m`.  Looking at just one will suffice here:

```
    if (m == 1) {
        int inp1;
        fdin = open(argsexec[input + 1], O_RDONLY, CREATE_MODE);
        dup2(fdin, STDIN_FILENO);
        close(fdin);
        inp1 = execlp(argsexec[0], argsexec[0], NULL);
    }
```

(The other two use `execvp` rather than `execlp`.<sup>1</sup>)  If an `exec*` family function call succeeds, the current process will be replaced immediately, so that the `exec*` never returns.  So if you need to redirect two (or more) `*_FILENO` values, the eventual `exec*` call has to be put off until after all other redirections are *also* done.

---

<sup>1</sup>One of these is not the appropriate function.  OK, no dancing around here: `execvp` is the proper choice. :-)

---

A third problem occurs if a redirect is not followed by a file name (see below).

The last two *potential* problems with this code snippet is much less obvious and needs looking at the whole thing.  Whether one is a "real bug" depends on how simple your shell is meant to be.

The `argsexec` array can hold up to 128 `char *` pointer values.  The entry in `argsexec[0]` should be the name of the binary to run—it's supplied to `execvp` after all—and to use `execvp`, `argsexec[0]` must be the first of however many `char *`s in sequence:

- `argsexec[0]` becomes `argv[0]` (in the program you invoke),
- `argsexec[1]` becomes `argv[1]` (the program's first argument),
- `argsexec[2]` becomes `argv[2]`,
- and so on ... until:
- `argsexec[i]`, for the smallest integer `i`, is `NULL`: and that tells the `execv*` family of functions: "OK, you can stop copying now."

Let's skip over definite bug #3 for a bit longer, and talk about potential bug #4: It's not clear here whether any `argsexec[i]` has been set to `NULL`.  The argument `f` to `iodirection` is the *last* `i` for which `argsexec[i]` must *not* be `NULL`; we can't tell, from this code fragment, whether some (presumably the `f+1`th) `argsexec[i]` is `NULL`.  To use the `execvp` function, it will need to be `NULL`.

If there are some I/O redirections, you will set some `argsexec[i]` to NULL.  That will terminate the array and make the `execvp` call work correctly.  If not ... ?

This leads to potential bug #5: In "real" Unix shells you can place I/O redirections "in the middle" of a command:

```
prog > stdout arg1 2> stderr arg2 < stdin arg3
```

This runs `prog` with three arguments (`arg1`, `arg2`, and `arg3`).  In fact, you can even put the redirections first:

```sh
<stdin >stdout 2>stderr prog arg1 arg2 arg3
```

and in some shells you can "re-direct" more than once (and then not even bother running a command, if you don't want one):

```
$ ls
$ > foo > bar > baz
$ ls
bar     baz     foo
```

(but other shells forbid it:

```
$ rm *; exec csh -f
% > foo > bar > baz
Ambiguous output redirect.
```

not that csh is anything to emulate. :-) )

If—this is a big "if"—you want to allow this or something similar, you'll need to "execute and remove" each I/O redirection as it appears, moving remaining arguments down so that `argsexec` remains "densely populated" with the various `char *` values that are to be supplied to the program.  For instance, if `len` is the length of the valid, non-`NULL` entries in the array, so that `argsexec[len]` is `NULL`, and you need to "remove" `argsexec[j]` and `argsexec[j + 1]` (which contain a redirection like ">", and a file name, respectively), then:

```
for (i = j + 2; i <= len; i++) {
    argsexec[i - 2] = argsexec[i];
}
```

would do the trick (the loop runs to `i <= len` so that it copies the terminating `NULL` as well).

So, finally, definite bug #3: what happens if a redirect is at the very last position, `argsexec[f - 1]`?  The `for (k ...)` loop runs `k` from `0` to `f - 1` inclusive.  If, when `k == f - 1`, `argsexec[k]` is a redirect, the file name must be in `argsexec[f]`.

But we just noted (above) that `argsexec[f]` *needs* to be `NULL`.  That is, if someone tries:

```
ls >
```

then `argsexec[]` should contain `"ls"`, `">"`, and `NULL`.

Here's what the "real shells" `sh` and `csh` do in that case:

```
$ ls >
Syntax error: newline unexpected

% ls >
Missing name for redirect.
```

You'll need something similar: a way to reject the attempt, if the file name after the redirection is missing.